# Sum of specific rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, sum

I have a table like this:

[image]

I want to sum actual values of same segment,same group, same date like this:

[image]

If I use pd.groupby, it don't seem like above table.

I would be very grateful if someone could help.
Thanks.

Comment: how did you try to group? `df.groupby(['segment', 'group', 'date']).sum()` should work. Also, dont post images of code/data but paste it as text in the question

Answer (score 0):

```
df.groupby(["segment", "group", "date"]).sum().reset_index()

# output
  segment group    date  actual
0       A     a  21-Jun       8
1       A     b  21-Jul       7
2       A     c  21-Aug       8
3       B     e  21-Sep      10
4       C     d  21-Nov       7
5       C     f  22-Jan       7
```